# Spring MVC + spring-social-facebook java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring-mvc, facebook-api, jackson

У меня есть работающее приложение на Spring MVC. Я хочу сделать вход через Facebook используя spring-social-facebook.

Я добавляю зависимость:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

При старте проекта получаю ошибку:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException

Я пробовал изменять версии jackson, но это не дало результата.
Подскажите в чем может проблема?
Я не писал ни какого кода используя эту библиотеку, а всего лишь добавил ее зависимость в [pom.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rQpIDloFSmaGv3UmW2MUAh63NHiZgfvg)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать последний `com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind`.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```